# How to create database objects in a schema rathern than dbo or dba in sql server

Tags: sql-server

i am connecting to sql server with user name as sa and Password=Password()345
i have a database named Demo , when i creating any database objects like tables or procedures it is placed in dbo. but i want to put in a schema like ABCD . how to do this . Can anyone tell me the steps . i am new to sql server

Comment: As a general you don't want to give you password to anything out on the internet. It's not helpful to the question in anyway possibly leaves you vulnerable and if nothing else makes you look bad.

Answer (score 1):

First you might want to create a schema:

```
CREATE SCHEMA somename;
GO
```

Then you create a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE somename.TestTable (col1 int);
```

SQL Server lets you even do it in a single step:

```
CREATE SCHEMA somename AUTHORIZATION sa
   CREATE TABLE tab1 (col1 INT);
GO
```

Comment: hi whenever i create database objects say a table it should be automatically in ABCD like dbo

Comment: Then you should make your new schema the default schema for a user. This might not be a good idea for the user sa.

Comment: Why is it that you are doing this? What is it you hope to accomplish sir or madame?

Comment: because we have a schema where the objects should be stored automatically when created

Comment: You should always [prefix the schema](https://sqlblog.org/2019/09/12/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix) anyway. Sooooo......

Answer (score 0):

It's as simple as:

```
CREATE SCHEMA NewSchema;

CREATE TABLE NewSchema.NewTable
(
   ....
);

CREATE PROC NewSchema.NewProc 
  AS ....;
```

Same as you would do for `dbo.`

You might also need to consider granting [applicable access](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187940.aspx)

To [move a user's default schema](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176060.aspx) to this one:

```
ALTER USER userName  
     WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = NewSchema;
```

Comment: yaa ,i need to grant. please tell me the complete process

Comment: Hi Stuart,Please tell me the process where abcd will be the schema name

Comment: No, username isn't the same as schema. To add the user to the DB bound to your new schema `CREATE USER [Domain\SomeUser]
WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = NewSchame;` or Sql std security `CREATE USER SqlUser FOR LOGIN SqlUser WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = NewSchema`. Server level logins must exist obviously.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE SCHEMA ABCD
GO

CREATE TABLE ABCD.TableName (...)
```

Comment: i want the default schema should be ABCD